# Eevee. I'm getting this weird random light out of my model and also in the render

Tags: rendering, light, eevee-render-engine

[image]
I'm new to blender i try to search online but i don't find any solution. So i randomly get this light emitting out of my model. can anyone help me please
PS:Sorry for my mixed up english

Comment: no i need the bloom setting to be turned on so some of my model emit light, but my problem is that random yellow and green light

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `Screen Space Reflection` in the `Render Properties` panel. I had this problem once and this solved it. Hope it works for you too!